# Custom Policies: Prevent unsupported locales even if language is passed directly to the user flow

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

We have started using some custom localized html files to show some localized headlines etc. to our users.

As per [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview#localize-content), we just uploaded a couple of html files for rendering.

```
https://contoso.blob.core.windows.net/{Culture:LanguageName}/myHTML/unified.html
```

However, when a user flow is started  with an explicit locale set (e.g. `&lang=es` or `UI-locales=es-ES`) and we **don't have a file for this locale**, we get an error page.

> AADB2C90002: The CORS resource 'https://anyhelpappreciated.blob.core.windows.net/es/myHTML/unified.html' returned a 404 not found.

We have set up `SupportedLanguages`, but this does not seem to do anything if the locale is passed explicitly. I don't want to have to rely on the applications not passing me this parameter.

```
    <Localization Enabled="true">
      <SupportedLanguages DefaultLanguage="en" MergeBehavior="ReplaceAll">
        <SupportedLanguage>en</SupportedLanguage>
        <SupportedLanguage>de</SupportedLanguage>
        <SupportedLanguage>it</SupportedLanguage>
      </SupportedLanguages>
...
```

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is "by design" and cannot be changed.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/47654

> For localization, you can provide the query string parameter, `ui_locales`, from your application. When you call into Azure AD B2C, your page is translated to the locale that you have indicated. This type of configuration gives you complete control over the languages in your user flow and ignores the language settings of the customer's browser.
>   You might not need that level of control over what languages your customer sees. If you don't provide a `ui_locales` parameter, the customer's experience is dictated by their browser's settings. You can still control which languages your user flow is translated to by adding it as a supported language. If a customer's browser is set to show a language that you don't want to support, then the language that you selected as a default in supported cultures is shown instead.
>
> The `{Culture:RFC5646}` claim resolver works in the same way. Meaning If a customer's browser is set to show a language that you don't want to support, then the language that you selected as a default in supported cultures is sent to the HTML page instead.
>
> The only case where an unsupported `ui_locales` will be sent to the HTML page, is when the app passes the missing `ui_locales` in the query string. In this case we consider that to be an application decision and allow it to override supported cultures configuration.
>
> So, make sure your application sends only supported language in the `ui_locales` query string parameter.